# Shuffle images javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, list

How do I get this script to inset all images, and not just one of them?
I just want it to inset all images randomly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = ['basketball.jpg', 'running.jpg', 'tennis.jpg', 'running-woman.jpg', 'swimming.jpg', 'cycling.jpg'];
$('<img src="images/large/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#images');
</script>
```

Comment: probably, you need to loop over it

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the insert order **random**, use a while loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = ['basketball.jpg', 'running.jpg', 'tennis.jpg', 'running-woman.jpg', 'swimming.jpg', 'cycling.jpg'];

    while (images.length !== 0) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        $('<img src="images/large/' + images.splice(index, 1) + '">').appendTo('#images');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use need to use loop to append all the images....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = ['basketball.jpg', 'running.jpg', 'tennis.jpg', 'running-woman.jpg', 'swimming.jpg', 'cycling.jpg'];

    $.each(images,function(i,v){
     $('<img src="images/large/' + images[i] + '">').appendTo('#images');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This will not add the images in a random order, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = ['basketball.jpg', 'running.jpg', 'tennis.jpg', 'running-woman.jpg', 'swimming.jpg', 'cycling.jpg'];

   for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++)
     $('<img src="images/large/' + images[i] + '">').appendTo('#images');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code picks an image, then displays it.
You need to refactor it so it will do this multiple times.

First, break up the operations:

```
    var images = ... // fill array

    pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // choose image

    tag = '<img src="images/large/' + images[pick] + '>'; // make tag

    $(tag).appendTo('#images'); // add tag
```

Then, set in a loop to repeat until the array is exhausted:

```
    var images = ... // fill array

    while (images.length>0) {
       pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // choose image
       tag = '<img src="images/large/' + images[pick] + '>'; // make tag
       images = images.splice(i,1); // take picked image out of array
       $(tag).appendTo('#images'); // add tag
    }
```

I haven't ran this, check that the array indexes I use for "splice" are correct to take one image out and to take out the right one from the array. You could also grab an Array remove function, e.g. from http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fisher Yates Shuffle algorithm to shuffle images in javascript

You can store your collection of images in an array.. As shown in the following code,you can pass the array to the function and construct your shuffle :)

```
def fisherYatesShuffle(array):
if len(array) < 2:
    return

firstElementIndex = uniform(0, len(array))
swap(array[0], array[firstElementIndex])
fisherYatesShuffle(array[1:])
```